# Fluuter Google Maps Place Mark

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am receiving this error on the web debug. Error fetching user location: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method placemarkFromCoordinates on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding)

```
 Future<void> getPlaceMarkFromCoordinates(
  double latitude, double longitude) async {
final String apiKey = dotenv.env['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'] ?? '';
final url =
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$latitude,$longitude&key=$apiKey';
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final data = json.decode(response.body);
  var address = data['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(address);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question, and also please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase your chances of getting help. It looks like the cause of the error `placemarkFromCoordinates` is not within the code you provided. Please providde more details so that the community can help you better.